# Android - Asynctask and ThreadPoolExecutor exception in User login authentication process

Tags: android, android-asynctask, threadpoolexecutor

In the LoginActivity class am using the Asynctask class to do the authentication for the fetched email address and password.

This is the main activity class which calls the attemptlogin function which in turn passes control to UserLoginTask class that extends Asynctask class, for authenticating the user.

But the execution always stops after, `Log.d(TAG, mUsername+ "--" + mPassword);` and throws an exception for ThreadPoolExecutor.

I am new to android development, so please help me understand what is wrong in the code.

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    // Values for email and password at the time of the login attempt.
private String mUsername;
private String mPassword;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ......

    // Set up the login form.
    mUsername = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_EMAIL);
    mUsernameView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);\

            ......

    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    attemptLogin();
                }
            });
}

/**
 * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
 * If there are form errors (invalid email, missing fields, etc.), the
 * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
 */
public void attemptLogin() {
    if (mAuthTask != null) {
        return;
    }

    // Reset errors.
    mUsernameView.setError(null);
    mPasswordView.setError(null);

    // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
    mUsername = mUsernameView.getText().toString();
    mPassword = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

            ..........

    if (cancel) {
        // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
        // form field with an error.
        focusView.requestFocus();
    } else {

        // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
        // perform the user login attempt.
            mLoginStatusMessageView.setText(R.string.login_progress_signing_in);
        showProgress(true);
        try {
        mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask();
        mAuthTask.execute(mUsername, mPassword);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
        //mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
    }
}

/**
 * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
 * the user.
 */
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    UserFunctions userFunction;

    private String isUserLoggedIn;
    private String TAG = "Feedback App";
    private String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private String result;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... loginVars) {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.
        mUsername = loginVars[0];
        mPassword = loginVars[1];

        try {
            // Simulate network access.
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }

                    Log.d(TAG, mUsername+ "--" + mPassword);

        JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(mUsername, mPassword);
        Log.e(TAG, "fetched json" + json.toString());

        // check for login response
        try {
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

                                            ........
                // Close Login Screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // Error in login
                //loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                return false;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // TODO: register the new account here.
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);

        if (success) {
            finish();
        } else {
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }
}
}
```

And this is the function used for authentication

```
public JSONObject loginUser(String username, String password) {
    Log.d(TAG, "jsonparser class - in login");

    // Building Parameters      
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(serverURL, params);
    return json;
}
```

The exception thrown is,

```
03-07 11:22:26.002: E/ActivityThread(650): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d06618 that was originally bound here
03-07 11:22:26.002: E/ActivityThread(650): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d06618 that was originally bound here
03-07 11:22:26.002: E/ActivityThread(650):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
03-07 11:22:26.002: E/ActivityThread(650):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
03-07 11:22:26.002: E/ActivityThread(650):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
03-07 11:22:26.002: E/ActivityThread(650):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
03-07 11:22:26.002: E/ActivityThread(650):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
03-07 11:22:26.002: E/ActivityThread(650):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
03-07 11:22:26.002: E/ActivityThread(650):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
03-07 11:22:26.002: E/ActivityThread(650):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
03-07 11:22:26.002: E/ActivityThread(650):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
03-07 11:22:26.002: E/ActivityThread(650):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
03-07 11:22:26.002: E/ActivityThread(650):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
03-07 11:22:26.002: E/ActivityThread(650):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-07 11:22:26.002: E/ActivityThread(650):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-07 11:22:26.002: E/ActivityThread(650):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-07 11:22:26.002: E/ActivityThread(650):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-07 11:22:26.002: E/ActivityThread(650):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-07 11:22:26.772: E/StrictMode(650): null
03-07 11:22:26.772: E/StrictMode(650): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d06618 that was originally bound here
03-07 11:22:26.772: E/StrictMode(650):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
03-07 11:22:26.772: E/StrictMode(650):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
03-07 11:22:26.772: E/StrictMode(650):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
03-07 11:22:26.772: E/StrictMode(650):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
03-07 11:22:26.772: E/StrictMode(650):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
03-07 11:22:26.772: E/StrictMode(650):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
03-07 11:22:26.772: E/StrictMode(650):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
03-07 11:22:26.772: E/StrictMode(650):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
03-07 11:22:26.772: E/StrictMode(650):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
03-07 11:22:26.772: E/StrictMode(650):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
03-07 11:22:26.772: E/StrictMode(650):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
03-07 11:22:26.772: E/StrictMode(650):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-07 11:22:26.772: E/StrictMode(650):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-07 11:22:26.772: E/StrictMode(650):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-07 11:22:26.772: E/StrictMode(650):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-07 11:22:26.772: E/StrictMode(650):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

And with this ThredPoolExecutor tab is opened that displays

```
public class java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor extends java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService {
// Method descriptor #17 (IIJLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;Ljava/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue;)V
// Signature: (IIJLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;Ljava/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue<Ljava/lang/Runnable;>;)V
// Stack: 3, Locals: 7
public ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit unit, java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue workQueue);
 0  aload_0 [this]
 1  invokespecial java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService() [1]
 4  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
 7  dup
 8  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
10  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
13  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 29]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: this index: 0 type: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: corePoolSize index: 1 type: int
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: maximumPoolSize index: 2 type: int
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: keepAliveTime index: 3 type: long
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: unit index: 5 type: java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: workQueue index: 6 type: java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue
  Local variable type table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: workQueue index: 6 type: java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue<java.lang.Runnable>

// Method descriptor #36 (IIJLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;Ljava/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue;Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory;)V
// Signature: (IIJLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;Ljava/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue<Ljava/lang/Runnable;>;Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory;)V
// Stack: 3, Locals: 8
public ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit unit, java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue workQueue, java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory threadFactory);
 0  aload_0 [this]
 1  invokespecial java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService() [1]
 4  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
 7  dup
 8  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
10  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
13  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 30]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: this index: 0 type: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: corePoolSize index: 1 type: int
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: maximumPoolSize index: 2 type: int
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: keepAliveTime index: 3 type: long
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: unit index: 5 type: java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: workQueue index: 6 type: java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: threadFactory index: 7 type: java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory
  Local variable type table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: workQueue index: 6 type: java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue<java.lang.Runnable>

Inner classes:
[inner class info: #7 java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$DiscardOldestPolicy, outer class info: #5 java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor
 inner name: #8 DiscardOldestPolicy, accessflags: 9 public static],
[inner class info: #10 java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$DiscardPolicy, outer class info: #5 java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor
 inner name: #11 DiscardPolicy, accessflags: 9 public static],
[inner class info: #12 java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy, outer class info: #5 java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor
 inner name: #13 AbortPolicy, accessflags: 9 public static],
[inner class info: #14 java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$CallerRunsPolicy, outer class info: #5 java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor
 inner name: #15 CallerRunsPolicy, accessflags: 9 public static]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be an exception thrown in (because of) your code. Check the PID of your app and compare it against the one shown in the logcat exception messages (e.g.: E/StrictMode(**650**) - PID here is **650**).

However, one thing I think you do wrong is calling **finish()** from **doInBackground** of your AsyncTask. I believe that you should not do that since **doInBackground** runs in its own thread and **finish()** probably should be called from UI thread (i.e. should be called in **onPostExecute()**

Comment: AElis - Thanks, i checked the PID as you mentioned in the logcat, and both PIDs are different, so the exception is not generated from my code. And i shifted the finish() statement to postexecute() function but it still stops the execution at 03-07 11:53:15.022: D/Feedback App(3605): admin@gmail.com--welcome Then opens up 'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor' window in eclipse. I have added its content above.

Answer (score 0):

Try integrating all the functions from other classes in your LoginActivity. For instance your loginUser function from UserFunctions class and your getJSONFromUrl from JSONParser class.

Don't forget to declare your serverURL String and add import if needed.

```
    public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    // Values for email and password at the time of the login attempt.
private String mUsername;
private String mPassword;

 private static String serverURL = "YOUR URL";

    //private JSONParser jsonParser;

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ......

    // Set up the login form.
    mUsername = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_EMAIL);
    mUsernameView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);\

            ......

    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    attemptLogin();
                }
            });
}

/**
 * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
 * If there are form errors (invalid email, missing fields, etc.), the
 * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
 */
public void attemptLogin() {
    if (mAuthTask != null) {
        return;
    }

    // Reset errors.
    mUsernameView.setError(null);
    mPasswordView.setError(null);

    // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
    mUsername = mUsernameView.getText().toString();
    mPassword = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

            ..........

    if (cancel) {
        // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
        // form field with an error.
        focusView.requestFocus();
    } else {

        // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
        // perform the user login attempt.
            mLoginStatusMessageView.setText(R.string.login_progress_signing_in);
        showProgress(true);
        try {
        mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask();
        mAuthTask.execute(mUsername, mPassword);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
        //mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
    }
}

public JSONObject loginUser(String username, String password) {
    Log.d(TAG, "jsonparser class - in login");

    // Building Parameters      
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(serverURL, params);
    return json;
}

/**
 * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
 * the user.
 */
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    UserFunctions userFunction;

    private String isUserLoggedIn;
    private String TAG = "Feedback App";
    private String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private String result;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... loginVars) {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.
        mUsername = loginVars[0];
        mPassword = loginVars[1];

        try {
            // Simulate network access.
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }

                    Log.d(TAG, mUsername+ "--" + mPassword);

        JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(mUsername, mPassword);
        Log.e(TAG, "fetched json" + json.toString());

        // check for login response
        try {
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

                                            ........
                // Close Login Screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // Error in login
                //loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                return false;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // TODO: register the new account here.
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);

        if (success) {
            finish();
        } else {
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }
}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) 
    {
        // Making HTTP request
        try 
        {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            /*
             *  if you are referring to a localhost from your device than use the http://10.0.2.2/ 
             *  instead of the http://127.0.0.1/ or http://localhost/. Because your Android emulator is running
             *  on a Virtual Machine(QEMU) and you can not connect to a server directly running on your PC.
             *  So your code snippet will be like this:
             *  HttpPost httpMethod = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8080/ + address insteda of the normal website name");
             *  Modify your url from the previous activity
             */
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            /*  If you come across connection problems and any action requiring data transfer silently fails
             *  the following line of code could be the reason of the issue. Add a line breakpoint and check 
             *  whether the request has been sent or not. Check your server ip, and make sure that your
             *  machine is visible.
             */
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try 
        {
            /*
             *  Here you should receive the response from the web, check out reader response from BufferedReader class
             *  If you receive a html page response then your server is not online or reachable.
             */
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                Log.e("JSON PARSER:","line : "+ line);
                sb.append(line + "n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            //Log.e("JSON", json);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try 
        {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }

}
```